# sfdisk restore partition table if two hardisk have different sizes

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, mbr

What will happen if i try to restore the partition table of a larger hard disk to smaller hard disk, for example: partition table of 250GB hard disk to a 80GB hard disk using sfdisk like this.

```
sfdisk /dev/sda < PartitionTable250.txt
```

Will sfdisk detect it?

I think there will be no problem if the partition table of a smaller hard disk is going to be restored on a larger hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably end up creating an invalid partition table.

I've never tried this, but here's what I expect:

- *sfdisk* should write the partition table to the device.  This will succeed, because the primary partition table is contained within the MBR (sector 0 of the drive), and any extended partition table is contained nearby.
   *(I believe, but am not sure, the extended partition table is stored within the first 63 sectors of the drive -- the first partition normally starts at sector 63.  Remember that the 4 primary partitions (or 3 primaries and 1 extended) are all contained within the primary partition table in the MBR.)*
- Any partitions in the table that exist wholly within the first 80GB will work fine.
- Any partitions in the table that exist partially or wholly *beyond* the first 80GB will *not work*.  Simply put, the table will refer to sectors that do not exist on that device.

You're generally correct in that a smaller drive's partition table restored onto a larger drive should not have a problem.